# foundation top bar row width undefined

Tags: zurb-foundation

I am having an issue with the following import

`@import "../foundation/components/top-bar";`

I get `Line 342 of _top-bar.scss: Undefined variable: "$row-width"`

Unfortunately I can't find much documentation about this variable.

Digging into the source of `_top-bar.scss` I get to the offnding line `342`:

`.contain-to-grid .top-bar { max-width: $row-width; margin: 0 auto; }`

The documentation says about `.contain-to-grid`:

`If you want your navigation to be set to your grid width, wrap it in div class="contain-to-grid".`

This means the class is optional. Therefore shouldn't `$row-width` be set to some sort of default to prevent the above error appearing (i.e if I decide I don't want to use `.contain-to-grid`)?

Answer (score 0):

Variables such as the one I encountered are defined either in a `templates/project/scss/_settings.scss` or my own `settings.css`. Therefore I created my own copy of the original `_settings.scss` and imported it (i.e `@import "settings";`).

In other words it was in the [documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html) the whole time under the section "Using Sass Standalone".